# Computational complexity of solving linear diophantine equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-science, diophantine-equations, homology-cohomology, computational-complexity

Is there any good complexity upper bound for checking satisfiability of a matrix system $Ax=b$ where $A\in \Bbb Z^{m\times n}$?

I found some estimate on computing the Smith Normal Form $N$ such that $SAT=N$ for invertible matrices $S$ and $T$, for example [here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1996/03/CS-96-03.pdf): unfortunately, it is not very clear from the paper how the matrices $S$ and $T$ can be recovered, there is only one note at the end of Section 1 that they will do it "in the future".

I found a few other papers dealing with complexity of SNF, but either they only describe special cases (square, invertible..) or I couldn't see how to use them (without the unimodular matrices $S$ and $T^{-1}$).

I don't know whether I need to compute the Smith Normal Form at all.

The matrix I have in mind is a (co)boundary matrix between $k$- and $(k+1)$-simplices of a simplicial complex, if it helps.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: this looks good for a start: http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/spring13/CSCI-GA.3033-013/lectures/lecture-2.pdf

Comment: Thanks Will: but I don't see in this text anything about computational complexity, just an outline on how to compute the Hermite Normal Form (moreover, an algorithm about which authors say that it might not be even polynomial)...

Comment: this seems closer: http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi10/cse206a/lec2.pdf

Comment: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.3720.pdf has actual references that appear worthwhile, refs pages 28-31 roughly

Comment: Just to be sure: by satisfiability you mean that $A$ and $b$ are given and you want to check whether there exists a vector $x$ solving the system (where $A$, $b$ and $x$ should all be integer-valued)?

Comment: Yes. I have already found one reference, but will be greateful for further comments.  Theorem 19 here http://e-collection.library.ethz.ch/eserv/eth:3348/eth-3348-01.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

I would leave a comment but don't have the reputation: check out http://www.math.udel.edu/~lazebnik/papers/dioph2.pdf, which also looks to have several useful references (in particular http://www.math.tamu.edu/~rojas/kannanbachemhermitesmith79.pdf for algorithms to compute Smith normal form).

Comment: Thanks and welcome to MSE. The second paper shows polynomiality, but it is not easy to read of from the proofs a more exact order. But I will try :)